# DbUpdateConcurrencyException for tables with foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

**Update:** Ahh! Dumb error: I had two instances of a Repository available, and, our implemntation requires that we provide a connection string for each Repo, so the two Repos were pointing to different databases, and I was adding an entity from one DB to another, and its id probably could not be found in the updated DB.

---

I'm running .Net MVC 4.0, with EF 5. We implement a repository pattern. In the following `Delete` method of a WebApi controller I have the following code:

```cs
int userID = UserHelper.GetCurrentUserID();
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

ExhibitLinkRepository el = new ExhibitLinkRepository();
el.setCase = caseID;

ExhibitLink link = el.All.SingleOrDefault(l => l.id == id);

//Mark Link Deleted
link.usermodified_id = userID;
link.datetimemodified = now;
link.deleted_flag = true;

exhibitLinkRepository.InsertOrUpdate(link);
exhibitLinkRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Where `exhibitLinkRepository.InsertOrUpdate`:

```cs
public void InsertOrUpdate(ExhibitLink exhibitLink)    
{
    if (exhibitLink.id == default(int))
    {
        // New entity
        context.ExhibitLinks.Add(exhibitLink);
    }
    else
    {
        // Existing entity
        context.Entry(exhibitLink).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
}
```

When I invoke `context.SaveChanges()` I get the dreaded:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Now, the ExhibitLink table has foreign key constraints as follows:
[image]

There happen to be triggers on the underlying DB for some of these related tables, but disabling them did not change the outcome.

I just don't get it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this code ever run concurrently? The exception you're getting happens when the number of rows affected by the update operation is zero. The only things in the where clause of the update operation are the ID of the record and its timestamp field, so if no rows are updated, it has to be because the record has been deleted or updated since you last loaded it.

Comment: @Asad, It's a Dev DB and I'm usually the only one that accesses this module, and therefore this table. Plus we don't delete rows from the DB just set a delete flag.

Comment: @Asad, Triggers wouldn't throw the exception because they would modify the take *after* my operation. Correct?

Comment: Well, if a trigger makes a change to a record, your DB context wouldn't know about it afterwards unless you cleared the cache and reloaded the entity from the DB. And this would cause your exception, because your cached in memory entity would have an older row version than the one after the trigger changed the record.

Comment: I meant if my update fired a trigger

Comment: Haha. Well, glad you found the error.